# Flickr Oauth for android

Tags: android, oauth, flickr

can anybody suggest me flickr oauth tutorial for android. I dont want to use 3rd party api like flickrj, etc. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flickr Authentication](http://code.google.com/p/flickrfree/source/browse/trunk/src/com/zmosoft/flickrfree/AuthenticateActivity.java)

> Code license
>   Apache License 2.0

Comment: This library uses the old Flickr Auth, rather than OAuth.

Comment: Hmm you're right, I guess [this code](http://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/source/browse/flickrj-android/src/main/java/com/gmail/yuyang226/flickr/test/TestInterface.java)'s `login()` does an OAuth